# __repr__ and __str__ not working in dynamic class construction

Tags: python, dynamic, path, autocomplete

I'm building an interactive file explorer inside the Python console, such that when I pass in a path, I get an object, then with a dot `.` the auto-complete starts suggesting the contents of the path, then I do that again to get to the contents of the subfolder, and so on untill I get to the file and it returns the path.

I have achieved my goal, except this little nagging thing: I wanted `__repr__` method, but it never worked.

Here's my code:

```
import os
from glob import glob

path = r'C:\Users\eng_a\Downloads'

def browse(path):
    my_dict = {'_path': path}
    tmp = os.listdir(path)
    key_contents = []
    for akey in tmp:
        key_contents.append(akey.replace(".", "_").replace(" ", "_").replace("-", "_"))
    val_paths = glob(path + '//*')
    for akey, avalue in zip(key_contents, val_paths):
        if os.path.isfile(avalue):
            my_dict[akey] = avalue
        else:
            my_dict[akey] = browse(avalue)

    def func(self):
        return self._path
    my_dict["__repr__"] = func
    my_dict["__str__"] = func
    obj = type(os.path.basename(path), (), dict(zip(my_dict.keys(), my_dict.values())))
    return obj
```

```
>>> b = browse(path)
>>> b
```

Unfortunately it keeps printing `__main__`.

Comment: Because those methods are for instances of the class. `type` creates a class which can produce instances which use `__str__` and `__repr__`. Try creating an instance and printing it: `print(b())`. If you want the methods to work for the class object you can override them in a metaclass.

Comment: @hurlenko makes perfect sense. So, there's nothing wrong with my implementation. Thanks.

Comment: @hurlenko does that mean that I need to work with metaclasses to get the behaviour that I want?

Comment: You can try to achieve the same behaviour for instances of your class. I mean the logic of your browse function

Comment: @hurlenko to be honest, it has just crossed my mind what you meant. So, the solution is just to add parenthesis in the return statement of the function. return obj()     ........ instead of: return obj. That's it, its working now because I'm returning instances of the class. Many thanks.

Comment: @AlexDeft. The "correct" solution, in my opinion, is to replace your function with a class. Calling a class returns an instance. I can post something if you like.

Comment: Sorry, I have the habit of browsing through the unanswered questions of users that post interesting questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `obj` is a class, not an instance. It contains a function `__repr__` that will be bound to an instance as soon as you create it.

A simple and elegant solution to this would be to replace the function `browse` with a class of the same name. Calling a class creates an instance (unless you really mess with metaclasses or `__new__`), so the interface you have now would not have to change. Internally, however, you would instantiate your class for every directory that you delved into.

Another thing that this would allow you to do is to have a truly dynamic solution. Right now you actually recurse into all the children of your root. This can be very expensive in both time and memory. Ideally, you would only want to list the current directory, and recurse into children only when asked to.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, join
import re

class browse:
    def __init__(self, path, directory=True):
        # Create an attribute in __dict__ for each child
        self.__path__ = path
        if directory:
            for file in listdir(path):
                full = join(path, file)
                key = re.sub(r'^(?=\d)|\W', '_', file)
                setattr(self, key, full if isdir(full) else browse(full, False))

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == '__path__':
            return super().__getattribute__(name)
        d = super().__getattribute__('__dict__')
        if name in d:
            child = d[name]
            if isinstance(child, str):
                child = browse(child)
                setattr(self, name, child)
            return child
        return super().__getattribute__(name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__path__

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__path__
```

This solution does adds an attribute for each entry in the root path. Files are recorded as `browse` objects, while directories are recorded as strings. Overriding `__getattribute__` allows you to swap the strings you request for full `browse` objects on the fly, instead of having to expand all your folders up front.

A possible improvement, given the intended use case, would be to remove the line `setattr(self, name, child)`. This way, you would not retain unnecessary references to directories that you accidentally browsed into, for example.

Comment: I'm stealing this.

Comment: @AlexDeft. It's still misbehaving for me in IPython when I get to a leaf, but the idea is sound. I'm glad you like it.

Comment: I think you have a bug. so there is a condition sayes "if dir" then you go inside that if statement, and you see again "if dir" inside setattr. It seems useless, may be you meant to check something else.

Comment: @AlexDeft. Thanks for the catch. The one inside should be `if isdir(full)`. It pre-computes the `browse` object for files so you don't trigger directory listing on them.

Comment: @AlexDeft Fixed now. I'm amazed it even works perfectly as expected in IPython, which is usually a bit reluctant to expand things for you.

Comment: @mad-physcist now it looks a pro piece of code. Looking back at mine, it is cringeworthy.

Comment: @AlexDeft. The only difference, I suspect, is that I've been doing this a lot longer than you. My early code was no better. While your code can surely use improvement, it's not as bad as you think. Just keep plugging away and asking questions.

Comment: @AlexDeft. I've rejected your edit. The lowercase class name was there to show that you can preserve the same interface as you had, even with a class. There are a number of examples in the standard library to support the idea that functions and classes have similar behavior: `range`, `list`, `set`, `enumerate`, etc. A significant portion of what we think of as "[builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)" are actually class constructors.

Comment: Your version doesn't work in Pycharm editor for some reason. Mine works seamlessly. I mean outside the console, while still writing the code, mine works and if you instantiate it in one line of code then refer to it in another, it works as if you are in the console, but you're still writing the code.

Comment: @AlexDeft. That's not too surprising. You have a function that returns the contents of a current directory. I have a class that updates once it's been instantiated. I don't think PyCharm can run your code until you tell it to.